# How to validate the fields of each TAB, if the mandatory fields of each TAB are not entered, do not enable the following TABs

Tags: html, jquery, validation

I have 5 TABs which have fields, I would like to validate the fields for each tab, if they are not entered, disable the following tabs, the following example only works with one, but it enables all the fields, some way to solve it

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>title</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>

<body>
    <div class="ibox-content">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Case Creation <i class="fa-solid fa-folder"></i></a>
            </li>
            
            <li class="disabled li1">
                <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="">Attributes <i class="fa-duotone fa-circle-nodes"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="disabled">
                <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="">Individual Involvement <i class="fa-solid fa-person"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="disabled">
                <a href="#tab4" data-toggle="">Agency Involvement <i class="fa-solid fa-building"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="disabled">
                <a href="#tab5" data-toggle="">Review Information <i class="fa-solid fa-memo"></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form id="createCase" name="createCase">
            <div class="panel blank-panel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="tab-content">


                        <!-- aqui inicia el tab1 -->
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="caseTitle" class="is-required">Case Title</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control tab_1" id="caseTitle">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Case Number</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="caseNumber" placeholder="Enter case number"
                                            class="form-control tab_1">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Case Number</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="t" class="form-control tab_1">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Case Number</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="dddd" class="form-control tab_1">
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Case Number</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="ddddddddd" class="form-control tab_1">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btnPrevious">Cancel</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext" disabled="disabled">Next</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- / AQUI TERMINA EL TAB1 -->

<!------------------------------------------ AQUI INICIA EL TAB2   ------------------------------------------------------>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                            <h2>Tab 2 Content</h2>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="caseTitle" class="is-required">Case Title</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control tab_2" id="c2">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Case Number</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="c22" placeholder="Enter case number"
                                        class="form-control tab_2">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Case Number</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="t" class="form-control tab_2">
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious2">Previous</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext2" disabled="disabled">Next2</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- -------------------------------- / AQUI TERMINA EL TAB2 ------------------- -->





                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                            <h2>Tab 3 Content</h2>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="caseTitle" class="is-required">Case Title</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control tab_3" id="caseTitle">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Case Number</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="caseNumber" placeholder="Enter case number"
                                            class="form-control tab_3">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
                                
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious3">Previous</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext3 disabled="disabled">Next2</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!--------------------------------- aqui inicia el tab4  --------------------------------------------->
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
                            <h2>Tab 4 Content</h2>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="caseTitle" class="is-required">Case Title</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control tab_4" id="caseTitle">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Case Number</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="caseNumber" placeholder="Enter case number"
                                            class="form-control tab_4">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
                            
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious4">Previous</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext4" disabled="disabled">Next2</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-------------------------------/ aqui termina el tab4  -------------------------------------------------->

<!-------------------------- AQUI INICIA EL TAB5 -------------------------------------->
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">
                            <h2>Tab 5 Content</h2>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="caseTitle" class="is-required">Case Title</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control tab_5" id="caseTitle">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Case Number</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="caseNumber" placeholder="Enter case number"
                                            class="form-control tab_5">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious5">Previous</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext5" disabled="disabled">Next2</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

<!---------------------------------- /AQUI TERMINA EL TAB5 ------------------------------------->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>



</body>

<script>
   $(".btnNext").click(function () {
        $(".nav-tabs > .active").next("li").find("a").trigger("click");
    });

    $(".btnPrevious").click(function () {
        $(".nav-tabs > .active").prev("li").find("a").trigger("click");
    });
    /*============== funcionalidad tabs ==============*/
    // Obtener una lista de los elementos que deseas agregar el evento
    const elementosTab1 = document.querySelectorAll('.tab_1');

    function validarTab1() {
        const camposTab1 = document.querySelectorAll('#tab1 .tab_1');
        const btnNext = document.querySelector('#tab1 .btnNext');

        const todosCompletos = Array.from(camposTab1).every(function (elemento) {
            return elemento.value.trim().length > 0;
        });

        if (todosCompletos) {
            btnNext.removeAttribute('disabled');
            setNonActiveTabsDisabled(false);
        } else {
            btnNext.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
            //setNonActiveTabsDisabled(true);
        }
    }

    document.querySelectorAll('#tab1 .tab_1').forEach(function (elemento) {
        elemento.addEventListener('keyup', validarTab1);
    });

    /*============== funcionalidad tabs ==============*/
    const setTabDisabled = (tabEl, isDisabled = true) => {
        tabEl.setAttribute("class", isDisabled ? "disabled" : "");
        const tabLink = tabEl.querySelector('a');
        tabLink.setAttribute("data-toggle", isDisabled ? "" : "tab");
    };

   const setNonActiveTabsDisabled = (isDisabled = true) => {
        document.querySelectorAll('.nav.nav-tabs li:not(.active)').forEach(element => {
            setTabDisabled(element, isDisabled);
        });
    };
</script>
</html>
```

So the idea is to go TAB by TAB to talk to the following tabs,
The following logic works only to validate the fields of the first TAB but enable the other TABs, the main idea is to go TAB by TAB, entering the required fields to enable the other TABs

Comment: sounds like you just want a stepper, seeing as your using Bootstrap perhaps take a look at a Bootstrap stepper like: https://johann-s.github.io/bs-stepper/